# How use $text $search with _ensureIndex and SimpleSchema in MeteorJs?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, simple-schema

I have no result in my search using $text $search with _ensureIndex and SimpleSchema in MeteorJs.

**mycollection.js**

```
var1: {
    type: String
  },

...

var2: {
  type: new SimpleSchema({
    _id: {
      type: String        
    },
    name: {
      type: String
    }
  }),
},
```

**search.js**

```
results = myCollection.find({$text: {$search: searchText}});
```

**this works**

```
myCollection._ensureIndex({var1: 'text'});
```

**With this, I have no result : why ?**

```
myCollection._ensureIndex({var2: 'text'}); // here, I have no result
myCollection._ensureIndex({var2.name: 'text'}); // here, I have an error on console
```

**Any idea ?**

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want several fields to be searched in with the same query I'd suggest :

```
_ensureIndex({
    "var1":"text",
    "var2.name":"text"
  })
```

I'd also make sure that all specified fields are Strings (typically if var2.name is a String, var2 isn't - not sure this is necessary depending on your schema but probably better)

Comment: Thank, with you suggest : I have no error but I have no result

Comment: could you post the code for fetching results? are you fetching from a spot where you are subscribed to the data? also why are you calling your collection with App.Collections instead of just with the collection name?

Comment: Thank @MathieuK , 1) my code for fetching results is : myCollection.find({$text: {$search: searchText}});

Comment: 2) are you fetching from a spot where you are subscribed to the data? Yes, because, this code runs on server side

Comment: 3) why are you calling your collection with App.Collections instead of just with the collection name? it doesn't matter here, but, it's just a personal technique, just to use one single global variable

Comment: indeed you're right my mistake was just about the quote : var2.name:"text" to "var2.name":"text"

Comment: Happy you solved it ;-) mind upvoting everything ? I want dem points :D

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
App.Collections.Observations._ensureIndex({'var2.name': 1});
```

Comment: Thanks @zim with you suggest, I have this error : stack: 'MongoError: text index required for $text query\n    at Object.Future.wait

Comment: i'm not sure what the issue is, however: in my own code, i don't inline "new SimpleSchema" like you have. i define the new schema above where i want to use it, give it a name, and then use that name. (that's helpful for arrays of the new type as well). I'm not saying that's the issue, but it might be worth trying.